# "Буду(,) когда вернусь": нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Попалась забавная вывеска. Но краем уха я слышал, что в этом обороте запятая то ли вообще не нужна, то ли не обязательна. Правда ли это?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указанная запятая нужна, т.к в данном случае здесь неполное придаточное предложение с союзном словом.Вы путаете цельные по смыслу выражения(которые очень похожи);в этом случае перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний запятая не ставится! Т.к.фразеологические обороты не образуют придаточного предложения и, как правило, эквивалентны члену предложения. Ср.например:сделать как следует (как полагается, как подобает), выполнить как должно (как надо, как нужно),достать что нужно (но: достать все, что нужно). Значение же оборота "буду, когда вернусь!'' не эквивалентно члену предложения. Подробнее - здесь:[Запятая между главным и придаточным предложениями; цельные по смыслу выражения](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#%D0%B7_01](%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Comment: Придаточное предложение может становиться частью неразложимого оборота. Ср.: Это то что надо (в значении "хорошее, самое лучшее"); Это то, что нам надо. Но в данном случае, конечно, запятая нужна.